# How to display this data with VisualForce?

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller-extension

Let's say I have an object 'Vegetables'. It has 3 fields. Name, Amount, Month.

So for each Month we have a record of the amount of each type of vegetable sold.

How would I go about displaying this in a format where the first column is the Name, then the columns to the right are the Month's totals.

Something like this:

[image: Example]

I was thinking I had to use an aggregate but I'm not sure I can write one that ends up with the data in the correct structure.  I'll probably use a Map> for the data.

The other problem I can't seem to figure out is the VF markup.

I would guess this is a fairly common problem. How is the best way to solve it?

thanks,

lee

Comment: I recommend the following resources [Visualforce Workbook](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.workbook_vf.meta/workbook_vf/workbook_vf_intro.htm) and the [Visualforce Developer’s Guide](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_intro.htm).

Comment: See if the answer to this question helps you http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23896/visualforce-getting-sales-revenue-by-month

Comment: @Jenny B that looks really promising. I'll fiddle around with it to see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the information is already in Salesforce couldn't you create a report and group the items using summary option and then show it as visualforce with the following code:

```
<apex:page >
  <apex:iframe src="/enterreportidhere"/>  
</apex:page>
```

Put the id of your report where it says enterreportidhere in the code above. Also please take a look at the Visualforce Workbook as one of the comments mentioned. Typically users on this forum will vote your question down if you do not post the code that you have tried. The Visualforce Workbook is very helpful.

Comment: I think this is going to eventually be the solution.

I thought about posting my code but I have about 3 different things on the VF page that I've tried. I was hoping someone could point me in a direction of a solution. I was thinking that this had to be a fairly frequent request from users that there would be a fairly straightforward solution by now. Jenny B had a great suggestion that might work. But I think the report is probably the best answer (and one I didn't even think of).

Comment: @LeeFranke when I first started using this forum I felt the same way. I needed a quick solution and I wasn't asking for code I just wanted to be pointed in the right direction, but that did not go over well in this forum. Sometimes now I will post 3 or 4 things I tried just because that way someone won't send you something you already tried or try to vote your question down. I'm glad my answer could be a bit of help to you. I wish you the best of luck on this.

Comment: I actually opened a ticket with SFDC regarding this. They confirmed the only way to display the data in this format was to create a report. They did send me an example on how to run the report when the VF page fires.http://peterknolle.com/asynchronous-reports-with-the-analytics-api-in-apex/